# Codepush is not updating the app

Tags: android, react-native, code-push, react-native-code-push

I am using code push to update the app at run time. I already updated app 4-5 times. Now currently I have added auth and share functionality to the app with third party packages. I have commented all the code for share and auth functionality. I also did some native code changes also.
   While doing code-push app is not updated. I got this error `'Unable to get the hash of the binary's bundled resources - "codepush.gradle" may have not been added to the build definition`
   As per document Codepush only update JS, CSS files. I already commented the new features auth and share. 
   I checked few solutions on the github, but none is working for me.

Note: 1. For testing purpose, I installed the app in device with auth, share functionality. Then I did some text change and then code push. Here changes are reflected properly.
      2. I have also added custom fonts to the app.